# Scroll with mouse in 'less' without clearing the screen

Tags: trackpad, macos

When viewing a long file in Terminal with `less` (or `man`, which uses `less` internally), I can use two-finger gesture to scroll up and down the file; it's great. But `less` on OS X has an annoying problem: When I quit, it resets the screen back to what it looked like before I started `less`.

```
% date
Sun 30 Oct 2016 16:18:23 CET
% man less
% (hmm... where did my output go?)
```

When I quit I want to see the next prompt appear below the last screenful I was viewing in `less`. I can achieve this by using `less -X` or setting `LESS=-X`, which suppresses the terminal initialization sequences. Unfortunately, `-X` also turns off the mouse-scrolling feature. **Is there a way to suppress the screen clearing but still be able to scroll with the trackpad?**

As I understand it, this would require using a different set of `terminfo` settings. I cannot make heads or tails of the whole `terminfo` infrastructure. Does anyone have a solution? I'm on El Capitan, in case it makes any difference.

Comment: See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/961719/how-to-make-less-pager-respond-to-scroll-wheel-and-not-clear-the-screen), which may or may not help.

Comment: That's exactly the same question, thanks! It helps, though unfortunately by explaining that a solution is impossible at the moment. The proposed hack is not a bad idea, though! (Many years ago I made some enhancements to `less`, so who knows...)

Comment: If you want to write an answer that just refers to the superuser.so answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is nearly identical to [a question asked on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/961719/how-to-make-less-pager-respond-to-scroll-wheel-and-not-clear-the-screen). Here's a portion of the answer:

> So there you are: Either you switch to alternate screen and the terminal's hack converts scroll events into keypresses for less, and the normal screen is restored when you quit; or you don't, and then there can't be any magic converting scroll events to keypresses and less doesn't understand the scroll events.
>
> So what could be done? Well, either implement mouse support in less and let it handle scroll events itself (and live with a nondefault click or copy-paste behavior), or implement another weird hack: upon quitting, after reverting to the normal screen, less could for the last time print a screenful of content, repeating whatever was displayed before you quit.